# Почему студия ругается на код из developer.android.com?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я пытаюсь создать приложение в котором можно будет листать страницы и читать что либо. Нашел статью на офф сайте вот [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager). Там написано создать вложенный класс который будет готовить нам фрагменты для вывода на экран (если я все верно понял), сделал все по инструкции, но студия ругается на эту строчку `return new FragmentSlide();`

Вот сам класс:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        }
        public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

            public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm){
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return FragmentSlide.create(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return NUM_PAGES;
            }
        }
    }
```

Сама ошибка

```
Error:(40, 20) error: incompatible types: FragmentSlide cannot be converted to Fragment
```

Я старался заменить библиотеки на app.Fragment и app.FragmentManager, не помогло. Странно что в примере который я скачал оттуда они именно их и используют, хотя на сайте в примере с кодом этого Activity использованы android.support.v4.app.Fragment; и такая же FragmentManager, оба варианта я испробовал, не помогло.
Как привести эти типы, что бы студия не ругалась?

Класс фрагмента:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentSlide extends Fragment {


    public static FragmentSlide create(int pageNumber){
        FragmentSlide fragmentSlide = new FragmentSlide();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page", pageNumber);
        fragmentSlide.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentSlide;
    }

    public FragmentSlide(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.
                inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide_screen,container,false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41348/discussion-on-question-by-amir-shabanov-------develop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сам фрагмент не из библиотеки поддержки. Замените импорт в классе FragmentSlide на

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

вместо

> import android.app.Fragment;